# Groovy DSL non-deterministic behavior

Tags: groovy, dsl

I'm using groovyConsole to see the generated class code of the following two Groovy scripts:

```
process test{
    output:
    file 'output.txt' into b, c

    """
    echo hello
    """
}
```

Here is its generated code:

[image: right one]

And here is the second script that differs from the previous one - this one uses parentheses in `file()` method invocation:

```
process test{
    output:
    file('output.txt') into b, c

    """
    echo hello
    """
}
```

And this is generated code from the second script:

[image: wrong pic]

As you can see, `process` is no longer a function but a variable. It confuses me because I would expect that in both cases `process` should be seen as a function call. Is this an expected behavior? Do I miss something?

Comment: It sounds like a bug in the Groovy compiler. Please consider creating a ticket so it can be fixed in one of the future releases - https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/GROOVY/

Comment: ok, i have already submitted such issue to groovy jira community, thanks